# Is everything a Tensor in TensorFlow, including operations?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been reading the documentation [on core graph structures](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/framework.html#core-graph-data-structures) and it seems there is a disagreement with what TensorFlow actually does and the docs (unless I have a misunderstanding, which I assume I do).

The documentation says there are [Operation objects](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/framework.html#Operation) and [Tensor objects](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor). It gives examples of such and thus I tried creating some and asking python what types they are. First lets do a constant:

```
c = tf.constant(1.0)

print c #Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
print type(c) #<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

it says its a Tensor. Great! Makes sense and it even gives me information about its contents.

I did the same experiment with what I expected to be an operation:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 10], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10]))
Wx = tf.matmul(x, W)
print Wx #Tensor("MatMul:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)
print type(Wx) #<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

However, as you can see, Tensor flow said that both Wx and c are the same type. Does this mean that there are no operation objects or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: See my answer on "How to understand the term Tensor" for some history: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849322/how-to-understand-the-term-tensor-in-tensorflow/37870634#37870634

Answer (score 0):

tf.Varible is an tensor, and then you assign a value to it, that is an operation, an assign-operation. Or you use tf.mul() , that also an operation

Comment: but when u print its type its not an operation. That is the core of my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are operations. You can get a list of all operations in the graph by `graph.get_operations()` (where you could get `graph` via `tf.get_default_graph()` or `sess.graph` or whatever is appropriate in your situation).

It's just that, in Python, things like `tf.mul` return the tensor that the multiplication operation produces (everything else would be annoying since it's tensors that you use as input in further operation).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but maybe this will clear things up a bit.

```
x = tf.constant(1, shape=[10, 10])
y = tf.constant(1, shape=[10, 10])
z = tf.matmul(x, y, name='operation')
# print(z)
# tf.Tensor 'operation:0' shape=(10, 10) dtype=int32
# z is a placeholder for the result of multiplication of x and y
# but it has an operation attached to it
# print(z.op)
# tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation at 0x10bfe40f0
# and so do x and y
# print(x.op)
# 
ses = tf.InteractiveSession()
# now that we are in a session, we have an operation graph
ses.graph.get_operation_by_name('operation')
# tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation at 0x10bfe40f0
# same operation that we saw attached to z
ses.graph.get_operations()
# shows a list of three operations, just as expected
# this way you can define the graph first and then run all the operations in a session
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with TensorFlow, but it seems to be a basic concept that `Wx` is a *symbolic handle* for the output of `tf.matmul(x, W)`. So you actually created an Operation, but accessing `Wx` will give you a representation of the result (even though it's not calculated until you run a session).

Take a look at the [TensorFlow FAQ](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/resources/faq.html#building-a-tensorflow-graph) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this outside the context of tensorflow, and just in base python.  Let's say you do this:

```
def f(x):
    return(x+1)

x = 0

print(type(x))
print(type(f(x)))
```

You get `int` in both cases, right?  But what if you do

```
type(f)
```

In this case, you get a `function`.  Same with tensorflow: the type of the result of an operation is a new tensor, but the type of the operation itself is not a tensor.