# In TensorFlow,what's the meaning of ":0" in a Variable's name?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    foo = tf.Variable(1, name='foo')
    assert foo.name == "foo:0"
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    bar = tf.Variable(1, name='bar')
    assert bar.name == "bar:0"
```

The above code returns true.I use `with tf.device` here to illustrate that the ":0" doesn't mean the variable lie on the specific device.So what's the meaning of the ":0" in the variable's name(foo and bar in this example)?

Comment: Does the assert return true? Have you read the documentation for `tensorflow.Variable` class?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes,it returns true,and In the [tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html),you can find some similar code,but the doc never explain what's the meaning of the ":0".

Comment: Gotcha. I was just reading over the source code. Can't easily spot it, though.

Comment: As far as I know it means "variable bar after 0th iteration" but I am not experienced TF user

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It has to do with representation of tensors in underlying API. A tensor is a value associated with output of some op. In case of variables, there's a `Variable` op with one output. An op can have more than one output, so those tensors get referenced to as `<op>:0`, `<op>:1` etc. For instance if you use `tf.nn.top_k`, there are two values created by this op, so you may see `TopKV2:0` and `TopKV2:1`

```
a,b=tf.nn.top_k([1], 1)
print a.name # => 'TopKV2:0'
print b.name # => 'TopKV2:1'
```

[How to understand the term `tensor` in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849322/how-to-understand-the-term-tensor-in-tensorflow/37870634#37870634)

Comment: When you create a variable, e.g. using `tf.Variable()`, you don't and you can't append a `:0` to the name but when you get a variable name with e.g. `some_var.name`, the name you get has a `:0`. I think this is the source of much confusion. In some contexts, a 'variable' is not really a variable but a tensor op that gets the variable, so that there's a `:0` at the end, but this is not really explicitly explained in the documentation.