# tensorflow's name convention?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Whenever using tensorflow variables's name, I have had a question why they ended by `blabla:0`. So I should use split function like `v.name.split(':')[0]`.

Despite there is same name's variables, the tail's name wouldn't be changed, like my expectation `aaa:0`, `aaa:1`.

Does anybody know why tensorflow does this?

I couldn't find this reason on tensorflow.org or via googling.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925652/in-tensorflow-whats-the-meaning-of-0-in-a-variables-name/40936352#40936352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offending integer is added in the [Tensor class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L327), and is the "value index":

> value_index: An `int`. Index of the operation's endpoint that produces
>           this tensor.

It's not always zero! For example:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.unique([1,2,3])
```

Prints:

```
Unique(y=<tf.Tensor 'Unique:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, idx=<tf.Tensor 'Unique:1' shape=(3,) dtype=int32>)
```

So the first output has the ":0" suffix, but the second has a ":1" suffix since it's the second output of the op.