# why does get_tensor_by_name require appending a port to the tensor name

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know that when getting a tensor by name that I must append an output index

ex)

```py
graph.get_tensor_by_name('example:0')
```

Where :0 is the output index. But why is this necessary?

[here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Graph.get_tensor_by_name) is a  link to get_tensor_by_name in tensorflow's docs. However, it does not mention specifying an output index.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849322/how-to-understand-the-term-tensor-in-tensorflow/37870634#37870634

Comment: As a concrete example `tf.nn.top_k(tf.ones((1)), name="top_k")` creates tensors `top_k:0` and `top_k:1` representing two outputs of that op

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In TensorFlow, names are given to [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Operation) objects (which correspond to nodes in the [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Graph)), and a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Tensor) object is named for the `tf.Operation` that produces it as an output.

Since a `tf.Operation` can have more than one output, to name a `tf.Tensor` uniquely, we include its index in the the outputs as part of its name.

Therefore, we chose the following format for the name of a `tf.Tensor` object, which is also the value returned by the [`tf.Tensor.name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Tensor.name) property:

```
<name of operation>:<index of output>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand this function! :( I couldn't find this anywhere. Please explain clearly what it does and what is the use of this function!!

Comment: @Sridharan If you have a question about this function (I'm assuming you mean `tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name()`?), then I'd suggest you ask it as a new question. From your comment, it's unclear what you couldn't understand.

Comment: What I couldn't understand is "What will be effect/use after executing that function?"

Answer (score 0):

The crux to understand the `get_tensor_by_name` function is to realize that a `TensorFlow` model is first specified as a graph during the **construction** phase.  In the question, `example` is the name of an operation node in this graph.   When this operation is run during the **execution** phase, output is produced by this `example` node.  This output is indexed by a number indicating its production order.  In this case, it is `1`.

The graph and its outputs described above were saved during an earlier run.  Later in a different project execution, this run time state was restored possibly by using `tf.train.import_meta_graph` and `graph` becomes a reference to it.  The function `get_tensor_by_name` simply recovers a reference to the saved second output of the `example` node from the restored run time meta graph.  You can now make use this recovered tensor in your own task during another session run.