# placeholder created in function not being recognized in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I found the solution to my problem via hit and trial but do not understand why it worked.

I am going through [getting started of tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started). I ran the code till the end of the following code block and it works fine.

```
W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
print(sess.run(loss, {x:[1,2,3,4], y:[0,-1,-2,-3]}))
```

Now, I thought that `loss` looks like something that should be in a function. I tried the following.

```
def get_loss(linear_model):
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
    return tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)

loss = get_loss(linear_model)
print(sess.run(loss, {x:[1,2,3,4], y:[0,-1,-2,-3]}))
```

But it gave me an error.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_26' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_26 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I then tried the following. The only difference is I returned `y` also.

```
def get_loss(linear_model):
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
    return y, tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)

y, loss = get_loss(linear_model)
print(sess.run(loss, {x:[1,2,3,4], y:[0,-1,-2,-3]}))
```

It worked. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `y` is not visible outside the scope of `get_loss()`. If you return `y` as in the bottom, then `y` is visible now, so it works.

If you don't want to return y, you may instead feed y with its name:

```
def get_loss(linear_model):
    # give y a name 'y'
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='y')
    squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
    return tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)

loss = get_loss(linear_model)
print(sess.run(loss, {x:[1,2,3,4], 'y:0':[0,-1,-2,-3]}))
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849322/how-to-understand-the-term-tensor-in-tensorflow/37870634#37870634) is some discussion about the **":0"** part of `"y:0"`

Comment: I understand that it is not in the scope. That was my guess. Is that dictionary actually using the variable itself as the key?

Comment: It uses either the placeholder tensor object or its name as the key. y is just an assignment (name) to the tensor object, and it's the only way you can access the object in your code.