# Integrating the loss of a keras model into a tensorflow graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

If I define this simple Keras model

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

l1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(32))
l2 = keras.layers.Dense(10)(l1)
model = keras.Model(inputs=l1, outputs=l2)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

Let's say I have the input and labels values stored in `train_examples` and `train_labels` respectively

If I also define a variable `some_var` that depends on that model's loss (I just use `model_loss` here for the sake of this example)

```
some_var = model.total_loss
```

How do I evaluate the value for `some_var`? I know it should be something like:

```
with keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    sess.run(some_var, feed_dict={ ?: train_examples, ?: train_labels })
```

what should go in place of the question marks?
I don't want to modify the model's loss function, just use whatever has been defined in the definition of another variable

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I evaluate the value for some_var?

```
some_var = model.total_loss
train_examples = np.ones((1,32))
train_labels=np.ones((1,10))
with keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    loss = sess.run(some_var, feed_dict={ 'input_1:0': train_examples,
                                          'dense_target:0' : train_labels })
    print(f'loss is {loss}')


loss is 3.1767444610595703
```

Regarding `feed_dict` keys,

1. for Keras input layer it's layer_name:0, in the above example, input_1:0 (layer name assigned by keras can be known from `model.summary()`)
2. When a particular key:value pair is not provided in `feed_dict`, tensorflow throws an error with the key that is missing.

   *tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor '**dense_target**' with dtype float and shape [?,?]*
3. Long answer on why ':0' is needed for the tensor name. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37870634/419116

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to "evaluate" and not use it in some further graph calculations, you can simply use a callback:

```
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

def getLoss(epoch, logs):
    print(logs['loss']) #or val_loss (print the keys of logs if in doubt)

callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end = getLoss)
```

Use this callback when fitting:

```
model.fit(x, y, callbacks = [callback])
```

If you can wait until training finishes, you can simply get the history at the end:

```
historyCallback = model.fit(x, y)

print(historyCallback.history['loss'])
```

Comment: thank you. What if you will use it in further calculations? for example, what if I calculate ```some_var = keras.backend.gradients(model.total_loss, modal.weights)``` and then use the result as an input to further operations. Do I still use a callback (and return the final variable in the chain) or is there an alternative?

Comment: No, callbacks are used for monitoring the internal state/stats like 'loss', 'acc' during the training process(at the end of each batch/epoch etc.) https://keras.io/callbacks/.